# Invalid identifier in trigger in my Oracle database

Tags: oracle, triggers

I want to add an entry to the table, created a trigger so that it generates an id. But I get an error.

```
create or replace TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_ON_INSERT
  BEFORE INSERT ON "EMPLOYEE"
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT next_id("SEQ$SYS_BUYER_SEQUENCE".nextval, 'EMPLOYEE')
  INTO :NEW."ID"
  FROM dual;
END;
```

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) 
    SELECT KPFUDB.EMPLOYEE_ON_INSERT(), 'Ivanov', ' Ivan' 
    FROM dual;
```

Comment: What's `next_id`? Oracle would do this for you(generating id)  , if your DB version is `12c+`..if so using a trigger would be redundant.

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan   is this my function to lay out?

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```sql
create or replace TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_ON_INSERT
  BEFORE INSERT ON EMPLOYEE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.ID := SEQ$SYS_BUYER_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL;
END;
/
```

then do not include the `ID` column in the `INSERT` as the trigger will overwrite any value you provide (or the default if you do not provide a value):

```sql
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)
SELECT 'Ivanov',' Ivan' from dual;
```

---

Or, from Oracle 12, you do not need a trigger and can use an `IDENTITY` column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee(
  id         NUMBER
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
             PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR2(20),
  last_name  VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

And a similar `INSERT` statement.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f36ed38dbf0c613915ed88799050da12)*